# An example outline of a spike (in agile modelling)

Tags: agile, use-case, user-stories, spike

I'm doing requirements analysis and was trying to find a good example of a spike. I seem only be able to find explanations of what it is.

For *system use cases* I have following outline:

- Name: The name should explicitly express the user’s intent or functional purpose of the use case
- Short description: The short description should express strongly in a few lines the major normal & alternative flow
  activity (Describe what the actor wants !).
- Trigger: A trigger describes the event that causes the use case to be initiated.This event can be external, temporal
  or internal. This is important for batch jobs.
- Primary actor(s): Each use case minimally has one primary actor, but more primary actors can be involved.
- Secondary actor(s) : If applicable, mention here.
- Pre condition(s): Preconditions state what must always be true before beginning a use case scenario.
- Normal flow: This is –together with the alternative flow– the main part of the use case.
- Alternative flow: Alternatives are acceptable variations on the normal case of processing/proceeding with as end
  result achieving the use cases goal.
- Exceptions: These are unwanted but necessary variations but that don’t lead to achieving the use case’s goal.
- Post condition(s): A post condition states what must ALWAYS be true on successful completion of the use case.
  This can be the result of the normal flow or of an alternative flow.

For *user stories* I have the next outline:

- Title: describing the purpose of the user story.
- Rational/Objective: describing which value is created by the user story.
- Implementation details: written in day to day language of the business, they contain the following subsections:

  - Context: Describing where in the system this story starts and what other information should be considered before starting development.
  - Normal flow: Describing the happy path that leads to the desired outcome.
  - Alternative flows: Possible alternatives. Not used extensively because an alternative flow is often a separate story
  - Exceptions: Describing conditions that will lead to a possible failure of the normal/alternative flow.
  - Remarks: Additional non-technical and technical information that should help the developer to realise the user story correctly.
- Tests: A list of tests that should be performed when the story is validated after development. Every test should
  include the expected answer.

So I'm trying to find a similar outline for a spike. 
From the description of a spike I think the following things should be at least included:
* Title
* Time-span
* User story: the user-story where the spikes originates from (however I'm not sure this is always the case).

What else should be in the outline of a spike?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is not about programming.

Comment: This question is off-topic because it's not within the scope for this site, as defined in [What topics can I ask about here?](//stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) Also see: [What types of questions should I avoid asking?](//stackoverflow.com/help/dont-ask) You may be able to ask on [another Stack Exchange site](//stackexchange.com/sites#name), *perhaps* [pm.se] or [softwareengineering.se]. Be sure to read the help center's on-topic page for any site on which you intend to post a question.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Just as much as required by your team members to get going. The team defines a definition of ready (DoR) and should enforce it self-responsibly.